# When sacred-texts.com website is down or unreachable, use this link instead

Tags: discussion, suggestions

When sacred-texts.com is down, use the following link instead.

E.g.,:

[http://web.archive.org/web/20160612014310**id_**/http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm](http://web.archive.org/web/20160612014310id_/http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm)

The extra "id_" in the URL will [hide](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/40912/25499) the Internet Archive header.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the id_ thing.  Someone who knows JavaScript should create a bookmarklet which automatically adds that to the URL.

Answer (score 10):

By the way this is not specific/limited to http://sacred-texts.com only. You can use [Wayback Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine) for any site which is archived. So, Whenever you find a website that provides resource for Hinduism is not reachable you can try http://archive.org/web/ :

[image: screenshot]

Select the latest snapshot available:

[image: screenshot]

You can close the header by clicking on close button at the header.

For more information visit [faq](https://archive.org/about/faqs.php#The_Wayback_Machine).

Though this may sound like advertising *web.archive.org*, worth to mention that it can be very useful to use whenever a web-site you want to visit is down or not reachable!