# Comparison chart of site progress over the years or over the last few months?

Tags: discussion, support, site-evaluation, data-explorer, data-dump

Is there a way to compare Hinduism.SE's progress with itself over the years or over the last few months?

What I want to see is a pic. like the one below for 2014, 2015 and 2016 to see if the numbers are going up or going down.

Similarly, if anyone wanted, for every month of 2016.

Is such a thing even possible? If not, does one of us need to manually capture data every quarter, every month etc. then do the comparison manually?

Snapshot of site progress (23-DEC-2016):

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way is to use [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/) as discussed [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/611/277)

You can find some snap shots for earlier months and year there.

I've tabulated data from available snap-snots and prepared some charts. That may help you for comparativ analysis. [Updated to include available stats of 2017]

[image: table]

[image: QPD]

[image: Percent Answered]

[image: Avid Users]

[image: Answer Ratio]

[image: VPD]

<sup>Note: LibreOffice Calc ([free-software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html)) is used for preparation of table and charts.

Comment if any correction in values.</sup>

Comment: Yes, you posted ahead of me, I got the same idea after my question. Wish they took a snapshot every month. It's very random. They only have 12 snapshots maybe you could add all of them to your answer, at least one from 2014, 2015, early 2016 etc.

Comment: @sv. Check my revised answer

Comment: I think it can be safely concluded that everything's good except people to answer questions. We have more curious people than those who can answer them.

Comment: @VineetMenon Yes visit [this](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/643/277).

Comment: This is sweet..

Comment: Thanks @Pandya for sharing this info. I'll create a draft soon for the same which I used to do last year. This will help our users to understand that how we can get out of beta and maintain quality on Hinduism.SE

Comment: Can you update this? 4 more from 2017 are available now [March](https://web.archive.org/web/20170317171521/https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism), [May](https://web.archive.org/web/20170517104301/https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism), [August](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810205414/https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism) and [December](https://web.archive.org/web/20171205125013/https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism). Thanks!

Comment: @BhargavRao Sure! Have a look at the update :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier way to check the stats. This is a privilege provided by the Stack Exchange for the users with >5k reputation (Only on beta sites. 25k on normal sites). So, you have to earn all the privileges for this one.

The last privilege we get when we reach to 5k is [access to site analytics](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics). After this privilege, we get to see the History, Traffic sources of the site. This is a restricted privilege but it can be shared on meta for the analysis of the site. **[Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) is the link to the site analytics**.

In the stats, we can have the data of questions and answers posted, votes cast. Votes include accept votes, upvotes and downvotes. Unlike a SEDE query, this information also includes deleted posts too.  We can also see page views, visits, new visits in a given period of time.

In traffic, we can see from which source, people are visiting our site. It is given in the form of pie charts.

Comment: Nice, It also provides the data in csv (comma-separated-values) format! Though Area51 stats like % answered, no. of users, answer ratio are not available, the statistics for posts, votes and traffic are very impressive and useful.